# Cannot differentiate image functions

Tags: python, tensorflow

In Tensorflow, I'm restricted from differentiating values that had operations like hsv_to_rgb applied. This is because of this code, I assume:

```
ops.NoGradient('RandomCrop')
ops.NoGradient('RGBToHSV')
ops.NoGradient('HSVToRGB')
ops.NoGradient('DrawBoundingBoxes')
ops.NoGradient('SampleDistortedBoundingBox')
```

What is the rationale for this? Are the subgradients that uninformative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That reflects the fact that gradients have not been implemented for these ops